# What are the soak, armor, and health levels for vehicles in cWoD or V20?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade, world-of-darkness, vehicles

I searched though the V20 PDF but couldn't find any advanced statistics (anything beyond maneuverability) for vehicles in V20. I'd like to have some armed players participate in a car chase and I'm wondering a) what kind of soak common vehicles have b) how many health levels different vehicles might have. This would be just for targeting the vehicle, not called shots at the tires/attempting to blow out windows, or targeting NPCs inside the opposing car (which I am assuming I would treat as behind cover)

Comment: Please note that invisible does not equal behind cover. It is a common movie trope to have a character kneel behind car's door, but unless the car is armored this is about as effective as hiding behind a wooden table - not very much. Even a handgun penetrates thin sheet metal with enough force to kill people on the other side. To be honest I'm beginning to think unless you specifically call shots to **avoid** hitting people inside, they would be dead long before the vehicle starts malfunctioning.

Answer (score 2):

Vehicles Stats for the 20th-anniversary edition only came with M20 in 2014/15, page 458 onwards.

Each vehicle is given with Safe/ Max. Speed (which translates to movement in combat), Maneuverability (which is a dice pool maximum to handle it), Crew & passengers (required and non-required people on board), Durability (which is the car's armor), and Structure (which are its health levels). There's also a weapon entry for some. Some lists of vehicles can be found later in the chapter, as can be rules for targeting weak points.

Depending on the vehicle type, the vehicle can offer each enclosed passenger its durability and structure as protection.

Of the 50 different vehicles, I offer the following 4 as exemplary vehicles:

| Vehicle | Speed (safe/max) | Maneuver | Crew | Durability | Structure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Compact Car | 70/130 | 6 | 1 (1 pass.) | 3 | 3 |
| Cop Car | 80/200 | 7 | 1 (3 pass.) | 5 | 5 |
| Bus | 60/100 | 3 | 1 (20+ pass.) | 4 | 8 |
| Hummer | 80/120 | 5 | 1 (1-5 pass.) | 5 | 8 |

Compared to the old WoD Combat Structure was roughly divided by 3. In turn, Durability is not rolled but directly substracts from all damage inflicted on the car, or other items, as the rules explain.<sup>1</sup> The example makes maybe most clear:

> Based on six successes scored on the Enlightenment roll, plus
> one automatic success for using the Forces Sphere, the kick itself
> inflicts 14 health levels of damage on the pillar. Use of the Matter
> Sphere reduces the pillar’s Durability to 4, so that kick deals out ten
> health levels against the pillar’s Structure of 6.<sup>2</sup>

14 levels damage - 4 Durability = 10, 10 > 6, so the pillar was destroyed.

---

1 - Mage the Ascension, 20th Anniversary edition, p.439.
2 - Mage the Ascension, 20th Anniversary edition, p.440.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is probably not THE answer, but AN answer.

I looked through some books but the only book I have been able to find any kind of information is World of Darkness: Armory. Unfortunately this is for the New World of Darkness, so it's not really what you are looking for. However, AFAIK the damage levels for humans and object didn't really change that much between cwod and nwod, so it might at least get your bearing.

> Durability: This is the vehicle’s material hardness. Any attack
>   against the vehicle has the vehicle’s Durability subtracted from its
>   successes before damage is applied.
>   (...)
>   Structure: This is the amount of damage the vehicle’s body and frame can endure.

World of Darkness: Armory, p.132

> Type - Durability - Structure
>   Subcompact Car 2 10
>   Compact Car 3 12
>   Mid-Size Car 3 15
>   Performance Mid-Size 3 15
>   Full-Size Car 3 17
>   Limousine 3 22
>   Police Car 3 17
>   Sports Car 2 12
>   Muscle Car 3 15
>   Sport Compact 3 12
>   Supercar 2 12

WoD: Armory, p. 135

So, for a regular car, you could say that it takes about 15 damage to render it destroyed, you can find more examples in that book - trucks, vans, bikes, even heavy duty construction vehicles. They follow a similar progression.

However, I'd like to leave a comment that it should be taken with a pinch of salt. These are all stats measured as if you were unloading on an empty car expecting to destroy it. During a car chase these would actually be rendered moot, as a seemingly innocent amount of damage (smashing front window or activating airbags) can cause the driver to lose control over the vehicle and do the extra 10+ levels of damage in a resulting car crash. Think of it this way: just as a human suffers losses to his Dice Pool when injured, the car would be progressively harder to control when driven in a banged-up state.

Also, do not confuse Durability with Armor. Just because the engine is tough enough to make **most** handgun bullets ricochet off its surface (durability 3 perhaps?) does not mean the characters inside are similarly protected. I'd say that a regular car from the table has indeed 3 Durability, but only 1 Armor. Sheet metal could at best redirect some glancing blows.

Remember, that being concealment does not equal cover. See [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConcealmentEqualsCover).
The shooter will know where the driver is and there is little apart from some rebars that could stop the bullet flying at him. So if you play any kind of semi-realistic game, do not treat people inside a car as in cover.

Of course, if your campaign is less about simulationism and more about gamism, this might be acceptable, but make a conscious break from reality rather than unintended misinterpretation.